# string variable inside vector causes massive error (WinMainCRTStartup)

Tags: c++, string, windows, vector, gnu

I have a string variable inside a vector that gets a string.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

vector <string> buffer;

main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    buffer[0] = "foobar";
    return 0;
}
```

It causes this massive command line compiler error that starts with:

> Multiple definition of WinMainCRTStartUP...

Then the error continues with roughly 500 lines of incoherent stuff.
I've successfully compiled other C++ programs with this compiler(GNU compiler). I don't know why this specific program is causing an error.

Comment: Trace the complete error.

Comment: How do you build your program? How did you set up your project? What IDE (if any) are you using? What version? What compiler?

Comment: Also, vectors are not like arrays, when you create a vector it is empty and any indexing in it will be out of bounds and lead to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems. The first of all you need to add return type to main:

```
int main() {
  ...
}
```

Second. You have an empty buffer, so when your are doing buffer[0] = "anything" you will corrupt the memory (what may be discovered later when another function will access to the corrupted object). This happened because operator [] is unchecked for vector. If you will change it as:

```
int main() {
  buffer.at(0) = "foobar";
  return 0;
}
```

You will get an exception.

Comment: But how does that explain an error at compile time?

Comment: @HarryJohnston good point! :) In compile time we have to just add: int main() instead of main()... :)